# TypeError: QgsZonalStatistics(): arguments did not match any overloaded call

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, zonal-statistics

There is no problem in running this code in qgis 2.x but it through error when I tried in qgis 3.

```
def _calculate_means(self, polyg_layer_files, raster_layer_files, attribute_names):
    # polygon_layer_files: list of absolute path polygon layer files
    # raster_layer_files: list of absolute path raster layer files
    # attribute_names: name prefix of newly calculated attributes (means from raster to polygon)
        for poly in polyg_layer_files:
            for rast, attr_name in  zip(raster_layer_files, attribute_names):
                assert os.path.isfile(poly), "File {} does not exist.".format(poly)
                assert os.path.isfile(rast), "File {} does not exist.".format(rast)
                poly_object = QgsVectorLayer(poly, 'zonepolygons', 'ogr')
                zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics(poly_object, rast, attr_name, 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean)
                check = zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
                assert check == 0, "zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None) returned non-zero value... check input layers!"
```

I am not able to figure what is the actual problem here. The error that I got is:

```
File "/home/work_dir/my_code.py", line 98, in _calculate_means
    zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics(poly_object, rast, attr_name, 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean)
TypeError: QgsZonalStatistics(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the 3.0 API breaks: https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_QgsZonalStatistics

Specifically, "QgsZonalStatistics() сonstructor now accepts pointer to the QgsRasterLayer instance instead of path to the raster file". So your rast object must be a QgsRasterLayer, not a file path.

Comment: comments out these two lines still not working! assert 
 # assert os.path.isfile(poly), "File {} does not exist.".format(poly) and 
                # assert os.path.isfile(rast), "File {} does not exist.".format(rast) ...any suggestion?

Comment: You need to construct a QgsRasterLayer from the raster path, just like you've done with your vector layer